# List of installed certificates from BM and their expiration

Tags: commerce-cloud, certificates

I want to add some external system monitoring for certificates, listed on "Private keys and Certificates" in commerce cloud BM.
[image]
Basically I need "Alias" and "Valid to" fields.
Is there any way to retrieve this info with OCAPI or some other SFCC API?

Answer (score 0):

This information is not exposed through any API at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. While this may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide quotes and/or links to verified sources for reference

Comment: @shamina, unfortunately there is no documentation or quotes.